# Disable inputs if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a ticket purchase form. You have to fill all the peronal information there.
It is also possible to buy a empty ticket, without any name on it. It just requires clicking on the checkbox, which makes all the input fields disabled.
        var inputsDisabled = 0;

```
    $("#three").change(function(){

       if(inputsDisabled == 0){

           $("input[name=fname]").attr("disabled", true);
           $("input[name=lname]").attr("disabled", true);
           $("input[name=email]").attr("disabled", true);
           $("input[name=sponsor]").attr("disabled", true);
           $("input[name=phone]").attr("disabled", true);

           inputsDisabled = 1;
       }
       else{

           $("input[name=fname]").attr("disabled", false);
           $("input[name=lname]").attr("disabled", false);
           $("input[name=email]").attr("disabled", false);
           $("input[name=sponsor]").attr("disabled", false);
           $("input[name=phone]").attr("disabled", false);

           inputsDisabled = 0;
       }
    });
```

When someone buys an empty ticket and presses a "back" browser button, he gets back to this form. The mentioned checkbox is still checked automatically but the fields are not disabled anymore. I tried to use the code below but it doesnt help.

```
if ("#three".checked) {
            $("input[name=fname]").attr("disabled", true);
            $("input[name=lname]").attr("disabled", true);
            $("input[name=email]").attr("disabled", true);
            $("input[name=sponsor]").attr("disabled", true);
            $("input[name=phone]").attr("disabled", true);
        }
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think a string has the property checked?

Comment: `$("#three").is(":checked")` and since `checked` is a property use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Comment: You can execute change(); after you add change event so it get executed on init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your if condition should be like this

```
if($("#three").is(":checked"))
{
  $("input[name=fname]").attr("disabled", true);
  $("input[name=lname]").attr("disabled", true);
  $("input[name=email]").attr("disabled", true);
  $("input[name=sponsor]").attr("disabled", true);
  $("input[name=phone]").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use either `.is(":checked")` or `.prop("checked")` and since `checked` is a property use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
$("input[name=fname], input[name=lname], input[name=email], input[name=sponsor], input[name=phone]")
     .prop("disabled", $("#three").is(":checked"));
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I think `$("#three").prop("checked")` would be better than `.is()`.

Comment: it does not fix the problem of **"back browser button**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=fname]").attr("disabled", $("#three").is(":checked"));
$("input[name=lname]").attr("disabled", $("#three").is(":checked"));
$("input[name=email]").attr("disabled", $("#three").is(":checked"));
$("input[name=sponsor]").attr("disabled", $("#three").is(":checked"));
$("input[name=phone]").attr("disabled", $("#three").is(":checked"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my vision of this:

The key here is **$('document').ready** it should fix problem with back button clicked

```
var checkbox = $("#three");

checkbox.change(checkState);
$('document').ready(checkState);

function checkState() {
    var inputsDisabled = checkbox.is(":checked");
    $("input[name=fname]").prop("disabled", inputsDisabled);
    $("input[name=lname]").prop("disabled", inputsDisabled);
    $("input[name=email]").prop("disabled", inputsDisabled);
    $("input[name=sponsor]").prop("disabled", inputsDisabled);
    $("input[name=phone]").prop("disabled", inputsDisabled);
}
```